# Как добавлять значение в массив в redux toolkit?

Tags: typescript, redux

Вот мой код редюсера, в нем не работает функция add, данные просто не добавляются в state,в payload приходят объекты с данными

```
export const Cardslice = createSlice({
name: 'card',
initialState: [],
reducers: {
    add: (state, action) => {
          return state.concat(action.payload)
   
     
    },
    addStar: (state: any, action) => {
        state[state.findIndex((i: any) => i.id === action.payload.id)].stars = action.payload.value
    },
    loaded: (state, action) => {
        state = action.payload
    },
    addToFavorite: (state: any, action) => {
        state[state.findIndex((i: any) => i.id === action.payload.id)].favorites = action.payload.favorites;
        console.log(state[0])
    }
},
});



export const { add, addStar, loaded, addToFavorite } = Cardslice.actions


export const selectCard = (state: any) => state.card



export default Cardslice.reducer
```

возможно я неправильно пытаюсь достать данные из state

```
export const FavoritesPage:React.FC=()=>{

const favoriteCards=useSelector(selectCard)

    return(
        <>
     
        {favoriteCards.map((i:any)=>console.log(i))}
        {console.log(favoriteCards)}
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: в payload приходят объекты с данными -> А какая структура у этого объекта? И зачем используете concat? Это же redux toolkit  (с иммером) можно мутировать спокойно.

Comment: при загрузке страницы у меня загружается данные с сервера, которые содержат в себе информацию по типу дата создания карточки,id,добавлена ли она в избранное и т.д. concat я просто использовал от отчаяния, сначала я просто писал [...state,action.payload] но ничего не выходит, я все равно не могу получить массив с данными из redux. насколько я понимаю эти данные даже не заносятся в state

Answer (score 0):

вы не должны менять state в reducer.  Нужно создавать копию, мутировать ее и возвращать новое состояние. React`у нужно старое состояние чтобы понять что изменилось. Тоже касается остальных редюсеров.

```
add: (state, action) => {return [...state].push(action.payload)}
```

Comment: во-первых typescript сразу ругается Тип "number" не может быть назначен для типа "void | never[]".Во-вторых, даже если убрать return я все равно получаю пустой массив

Comment: ну типы вы сами уж как нибудь, я только кусочек кода вижу

Comment: вообщем я пофиксил эту проблему.Я изначально пробовал делать return[...state,action.payload] и это работает, но насколько я понял проблема была в том, что в навбаре у меня был Nav.Link с аттрибутом href, после того как добавил просто NavLink с аттрибутом to данные появлялись, но у меня появилась новая проблема, почему то данные стали дублироваться если несколько раз зайти на эту страницу, но это уже совсем другая история)